# subquery (Incorrect arguments to AGAINST) using Mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, full-text-search, match-against

When I execute this  **query** with  **MATCH AGAINST** using MySql (*see Query 1st*) the issue in this query they has generated an error like this (*see error*) or when I execute the same **query** with **=**  they executed normally(*see Query 2nd*).

My question is what am I doing wrong with against statement?

> Query 1st

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(up.`user_id`) 
FROM `users_post` up WHERE MATCH (up.`user_id`) AGAINST (uf.`user_id`)) 
AS user_count 
FROM `users` uf
```

> Error

```
enter code hereError Code : 1210
Incorrect arguments to AGAINST
(0 ms taken)
```

**Update**

> Query 2nd

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(up.`user_id`) 
FROM `users_post` up WHERE up.`user_id` = uf.`user_id`) 
AS user_count 
FROM `users` uf
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the argument for `AGAINST` must be a literal string, for example `'Fred'`. It is not allowed to use a column name like `uf.user_id`.

```
MATCH (up.`user_id`) AGAINST (uf.`user_id`)
--                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not allowed!
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match):

> The search string must be a literal string, not a variable or a column name.

You probably need to use `LIKE` instead of `MATCH`, though you should note that it will be much slower.

Comment: Thank for sharing your experience

Comment: Alternate solution to do what?