# Compare 2 tables using match

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have 2 tables **table1** and **table2**. Table1 consist of paragraph which is a news article including some company codes/names, while table2 is a dictionary consist of 2 columns which are company code and the company name.

Using MYSQL FTS function MATCH i want to compare the article with all items/dictionary in table2 
( both of columns )

```
SELECT * FROM pyproject.table1 WHERE MATCH (Paragraph) against
(SELECT * FROM pyproject.table2' with query expansion);
```

It seems to produce an error

How to check whether the article matched with the dictionary, the data in **table1** will be selected and the **company code** column in **table2** is included/joined together with the data in **table1**.

So if the article in **table1** consist of multiple company codes, it will be duplicated and added appropriate company codes

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to type in two columns of table2 statically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465758/subquery-incorrect-arguments-to-against-using-mysql) that [you've provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864664/compare-2-tables-using-match/56865133?noredirect=1#comment100282587_56865133) `AGAINST` doesn't work with columns. Instead you can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT
    t1.Paragraph,
    t2.CompanyCode
FROM pyproject.table1 t1
INNER JOIN pyproject.table2 t2 ON (
    (t1.Paragrah LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.CompanyCode, '%')) OR
    (t1.Paragrah LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.CompanyName, '%'))
    )
;
```

Comment: I tried your query and yield an error "Incorrect argument to AGAINST" , referring to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465758/subquery-incorrect-arguments-to-against-using-mysql . It seems impossible to match against a column.

Comment: @FH337 Thanks for your information. I've updated the answer to provide an alternative solution.

Comment: it works like charm sir, thank you. I add  WHERE t2.CompanyCode IS NOT NULL OR t2.CompanyName IS NOT NULL;. So it will only return the article which has the company code or company name

Comment: @FH337 Hm, I think you should rather use `INNER JOIN` then. It filters out only the matched rows in both tables. Updated the answer accordingly.